# How do I move a file from one place to another in ubuntu?

Tags: live-usb

I'm trying to create a bootable USB using an ISO file, so I downloaded unetbootin but for whatever reason, unetbootin does not provide the option (no it doesn't!) of looking into my home folder to find the ISO image. It only sees the file system. So I tried moving the ISO image to the file system so the program would see it but it says I don't have ???PERMISSION???? to do this?? WTH??

I'm new to Ubuntu and I don't know how to get around this. I'm using ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1):

If for whatever reason a program opened the root directory instead of your home folder in the Open dialog you can easily navigate to your home folder - it is in `/home/(your user name)/`

You should not move files outside of your home directory.

Also, "I downloaded unetbootin" worries me - where did you download it from? You should avoid downloading and installing stuff manually (not from Software Center), at least until you're a bit more proficient with Linux. Since `unetbootin` is in Ubuntu repositories, you can install it from Software Center or using `sudo apt-get install unetbootin`.

However, this may not even be necessary - there is a program installed in Ubuntu by default which is called "Startup Disk Creator". No need to even install it. You can create a bootable USB with it just fine.

Comment: @UriHerrera: Oops, my bad, I always thought they're the same program.